# Pandas resample with percentage change

Tags: pandas

I am trying to resample my df to get an yearly data filling by percentage change.

Here is my dataframe.

```
data = {'year': ['2000', '2000', '2003', '2003', '2005', '2005'],
    'country':['UK', 'US', 'UK','US','UK','US'],
    'sales': [0, 10, 30, 25, 40, 45],
    'cost': [0, 100, 300, 250, 400, 450]
    }
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
dfL=df.copy()
dfL.year=dfL.year.astype('str') + '-01-01 00:00:00.00000'
dfL.year=pd.to_datetime(dfL.year)
dfL=dfL.set_index('year')
dfL

    country sales   cost
year            
2000-01-01  UK  0   0
2000-01-01  US  10  100
2003-01-01  UK  30  300
2003-01-01  US  25  250
2005-01-01  UK  40  400
2005-01-01  US  55  550
```

I would like to get an output like the below..

```
    country sales   cost
year            
2000-01-01  UK  0   0
2001-01-01  UK  10  100
2002-01-01  UK  20  200
2003-01-01  UK  30  300
2004-01-01  UK  35  350
2005-01-01  UK  40  400
2000-01-01  US  10  100
2001-01-01  US  15  150
2002-01-01  US  20  200
2003-01-01  US  25  250
2004-01-01  US  35  350
2005-01-01  US  45  450
```

I hope I would need to do a resample yearwise. but not very sure about the apply function to use.
Can any one help ?

Answer (score 3):

Using `resample` + `interpolate` and reshape method `stack` and `unstack`

```
dfL=dfL.set_index('country',append=True).unstack().resample('YS').interpolate().stack().reset_index(level=1)
dfL
Out[309]: 
           country   cost  sales
year                            
2000-01-01      UK    0.0    0.0
2000-01-01      US  100.0   10.0
2001-01-01      UK  100.0   10.0
2001-01-01      US  150.0   15.0
2002-01-01      UK  200.0   20.0
2002-01-01      US  200.0   20.0
2003-01-01      UK  300.0   30.0
2003-01-01      US  250.0   25.0
2004-01-01      UK  350.0   35.0
2004-01-01      US  350.0   35.0
2005-01-01      UK  400.0   40.0
2005-01-01      US  450.0   45.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a pivot_table to do this and then resample:

```
In [11]: res = dfL.pivot_table(index="year", columns="country", values=["sales", "cost"])

In [12]: res
Out[12]:
           cost      sales
country      UK   US    UK  US
year
2000-01-01    0  100     0  10
2003-01-01  300  250    30  25
2005-01-01  400  450    40  45

In [13]: res.resample("YS").interpolate()
Out[13]:
             cost        sales
country        UK     US    UK    US
year
2000-01-01    0.0  100.0   0.0  10.0
2001-01-01  100.0  150.0  10.0  15.0
2002-01-01  200.0  200.0  20.0  20.0
2003-01-01  300.0  250.0  30.0  25.0
2004-01-01  350.0  350.0  35.0  35.0
2005-01-01  400.0  450.0  40.0  45.0
```

Personally I'd keep it in this format, but if you want to stack it back, you can stack and reset_index:

```
In [14]: res.resample("YS").interpolate().stack(level=1).reset_index(level=1)
Out[14]:
           country   cost  sales
year
2000-01-01      UK    0.0    0.0
2000-01-01      US  100.0   10.0
2001-01-01      UK  100.0   10.0
2001-01-01      US  150.0   15.0
2002-01-01      UK  200.0   20.0
2002-01-01      US  200.0   20.0
2003-01-01      UK  300.0   30.0
2003-01-01      US  250.0   25.0
2004-01-01      UK  350.0   35.0
2004-01-01      US  350.0   35.0
2005-01-01      UK  400.0   40.0
2005-01-01      US  450.0   45.0
```